# Resharper navigate to a concrete implementation of a generic interface?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is there anyway to get Resharper to navigate to the concrete implementation of an generic interface for a specific type.

E.g. `ICommandHandler<T>` and find the concrete implementation? I can get Resharper to show all implementations of `ICommandHandler` but not allow me to easily get to the implementation of the type T. We have hundreds of handlers and navigating is getting slower.

We are using Resharper 7.1

Update

Examples include things like:

```
public class AddStockRequestLineItemCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<AddStockRequestLineItemCommand>
public class RemoveStockRequestLineItemCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<RemoveStockRequestLineItemCommand>
public class StockRequestFufillingUpdateCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<StockRequestFufilingUpdateCommand>
```

Usage like in MVC controller constructor like:

```
public StockRequestController( ICommandHandler<RemoveStockRequestLineItemCommand> stockRequestLineItemRemoveHandler)
{
    this.stockRequestLineItemRemoveHandler = stockRequestLineItemRemoveHandler;
}
```

I'd love to be able to click on `ICommandHandler<RemoveStockRequestLineItemCommand>` and go to the implementing class `RemoveStockRequestLineItemCommandHandler`

Comment: Could you show a couple of example signatures? I take it CTRL-F12 doesn't do the job...

Comment: No ctrl + F12 just lists hundreds of ICommandHandler implementations. It doesn't care about the <T> generic

Comment: +1 for the question, I'd love to be able to do this as well but I don't think ReSharper's clever enough

Comment: Yeah our entire application is all about SRP. CommandHandlers, Validators, DomainEventHandlers etc etc. I love the purity - starting to dislike the navigation. I saw a plugin called Agent Mulder that did clever stuff to detect whether an implemenation was being used by DI. So if a plugin can do that surely JetBrains can show items implementing a generic interface?

Answer (score 4):

Resharper 9.1.1 supports finding the usages of a generic interface. Right click on IComamndHandler and it will show you the usages. However, it would appear, still no way of finding implementations.

Best solution we came up with was

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="ChangePersonAddressCommandHandler"/>
/// </summary>
```

Using cref link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837134.aspx and template and added this above the command or in our controller.

Would love not to have to do this and just navigate straight there with Resharper

Comment: Did you actually find a way to navigate in ReSharper 8 or higher?

Comment: Nope. Description sounded like you could but as far as I can see you can't

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper 2016.1 RTM now supports navigating to the concrete implementation of a generic type using Ctrl+F12.

Answer (score 1):

If I right click on the base object I get a context menu that offers:

```
Go to Implementation (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+B)
```

selecting that will then offer me the various derived objects (in your case the classes)

Comment: But that's the point. The OP wants to go directly to the derived type based on the generic argument, not to see the list of choices.